# ASP.Net Web API - How can I make it so that prefixes are not required when model binding from the query string?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

In ASP.Net Web API (RC) I have a test model class like so:

```
[ModelBinder]
public class TestRequest
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public TestRequest Get(TestRequest model)
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Now if I invoke the action via:

`http://.../test?foo=abc&bar=xyz`

neither values bind, because the model binder is expecting model prefixes, such that I actually need to call:

`http://.../test?model.foo=abc&model.bar=xyz`

I can understand that this is so that other action parameters can bind correctly, but in my case the model is a clean way of encapsulating all the possible action parameters so that I don't need to have a nasty action method signature with a whole lot of optional parameters. It also allows for easy model validation.

Is there any easy way to cause model binding to behave the same way as it would in MVC, or in a POST request?

Comment: Does the `FromUri` attribute make any difference? (As per [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx))?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `ModelBinder` attribute from your model class should work in the example you've posted. You'll run into issues for more complex method signatures, see Rick Strahl's comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx#10302750